# Is it possible to access the Class object in a static method?

Tags: java

Consider the following Java class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void doStuff()
    {
        // boring stuff here
    }
}
```

Is it possible to access either the class literal `Foo.class`, or just the class name `"Foo"` from within a static method such as `doStuff()`? In a non-static method I would just call `this.getClass()`, but there is no `this` to use in a static method.

---

**Edit:** sorry this wasn't clear - I want to do this with explicitly using the class literal `Foo.class`.

Comment: To literally answer your question, yes, you can use `Foo.class` in a static method, but not `this.getClass()`.  This only reason this would be an issue is Java's quirky static method inheritance (seriously, static methods should not fall through to child classes... c# explicitly forbids this).

Comment: Static methods are not virtual in Java. This is one of the reasons factory pattern is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Java doesn't give you a good way to do this. You just have to reference `Foo.class`. This is something that is a regular annoyance for me.

For logging I solved it (the idea for the solution came from Log5j) by reading the stack, because it got really annoying to restate the class for every logger every time. Fortunately modern IDEs make it relatively painless, so that refactoring isn't really negatively impacted if you have to change the name of the class.

EDIT: Some code:

```
private static StackTraceElement getCallerStackTraceElement(StackTraceElement[] elements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].getClassName().equals(MyLogger.class.getName())) {
            return elements[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

MyLogger in this case is the class where this method exists. It finds itself in the stacktrace and goes one earlier, and then extracts the class from the StackTraceElement.

The StackTraceElement[] array can be retrieved by either new Exception().getStackTrace(), or Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(); The way this method is written it assumes the stacktrace is created on the first method call into MyLogger.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you did exactly? Perhaps add a little code?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Class<Foo> clazz = Foo.class`

---

If you need something like:

```
class Foo {
    static Class foo(){return the current class}
}

class Bar extends Foo {

}
```

and expect `Bar.foo()` to return `Bar` if called on `Bar`, and `Foo` if called on `Foo` - you have something wrong in your design and perhaps you need to make the methods non-static.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Foo.class`.  You don't have to worry about inheritance or anything like that, since there's no object associated with a static method.

Comment: The whole point of my question was to do it **without** referencing `Foo.class`.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with static methods, you can think of them as libraries, where the class name becomes the library name. You tell the compiler which bar() method to run by specifying the library (class) name. `Foo.bar()` vs. `Bar.bar()`.

The method itself has no parent and no instance, therefore, it can't use reflection to know what class it's part of. However, you can add a reflection method.

You can add a static method to the class that answers itself what class it's in:

```
public class Foo {

    private static class self() {
        return Foo.class;
    }

    public static void doStuff()
    {
        // Use self() to reference the Foo class
    }
}
```

Notice that I made the self() method private because outside of the class, it makes no sense.

This works because the self() method is visible from inside the class, and inside the static method.

In contrast, PHP has a `self` construct to reference the current class.